# Send email to multiple users

Tags: python, smtp

I want to send an email to multiple users. Right now, I am only able to send it to one user. I want to make a property file so that whenever I need to add or remove any user from the list, I dont have to edit anything in .py file.

I am able to send the email to one user

```
import smtplib
import email.utils
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


me = abc@an.com
you = jud@gm.com
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject']="subject of the email"
msg['From"]=me
msg['To']=you
text="hi"

html= '''body of email'''
part1=MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part1=MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
s = smtplib.SMTP(host,port)
s.sendmail(me,you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

the email should go to multiple users.

Comment: A proper `multipart/alternative` message should really contain the same content in both parts, at least approximately.

Comment: The `me` and `you` assignments are not valid Python syntax. Presumably you meant for the values to be quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `you` can be a list of email addresses. You will need to adapt your code to set the `To:` header to accept a list of strings

```
msg['To'] = '.'.join(you)
```

or you can use a placeholder like

```
msg['To'] = 'undisclosed-recipients:;'
```

but other than that, your existing code should just work.

In some more detail, the latter is basically equivalent to putting all the addresses in a `Bcc:` header, so that the recipients cannot see each others' addresses.

To populate `you` from a file, try

```
with open(filename) as f:
    you = f.readlines()
```

where the file contains one email address per line.